# How to animate non-animatable properties with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make a smoothzoom for images. This is my code for that. But, I can't animate it.

```
<img src="images/2.jpg" class="sz" onclick="zoomIn()" id="sz">

    function zoomIn() {
  document.getElementById('dark').setAttribute('style', 'display:block;')
  document.getElementById('sz').setAttribute('style', 'z-index: 1; position:absolute; left:0; right:0;top:0; bottom:0; margin:auto;max-width:100%;max-height:100%;overflow:auto;');
}
    img.sz {
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: What is the element 'dark'?

Comment: How do you think to animate it? What's the result you want to get?

Comment: element 'dark' is the way I dark the page when image zooms

Comment: I need to make this like Quora does